phpMyAdmin error - mysqli extension is missing
I'm getting this error:
phpMyAdmin - Error The mysqli extension is missing. 
Please check your PHP configuration. See our documentation for more information.

loaded configuration file: C:\MAMP\conf\php8.3.11\php.ini
in system environment variables, the path is: C:\MAMP\bin\php\php8.3.11
the mysqli extension in the php.ini file is uncommented.
mysqli support is enabled when viewing phpinfo, and it's using the correct version:
 Client API library version : mysqlnd 8.3.11.

One post that I've tried:
The mysqli extension is missing. Please check your PHP configuration
I've tried reinstalling mamp, changing the system environment variable path, since mamp also has its own installation of php versions, checking to make sure I uncommented the lines. I was expecting something to stick, but not on this device.
I've also checked to make sure that the correct php.ini file is being loaded. Any suggestions on why this isn't working for me? Thanks for reading.

looks like your phpmyadmin is set up to use some other php version (if we take for granted that everything is indeed installed correctly)

No, phpinfo gives 8.3.11, which is what php -v gives. It's using the same version.

which phpinfo? one built in into phpmyadmin? or just random phpinfo unrelated to pma?

in your place i would ditch pma and use a more reliable tool such as datagrip or wrkbench

Yes, I've been using the one that phpmyadmin has been configured to use. Also, I'm planning on doing a project with laravel, so I need PHP to work.

Laravel doesn't use mysqli

Are you sure? The class that I took used mysqli on a laravel project for database functions.
